# HTTP Request JS - How to extract numbers out of a list, save them to variables and use them for further treatment?

Tags: javascript, arrays, http, meteor, xmlhttprequest

I already searched for that topic, but couldn´t find an answer that worked for me.

I receive an answer from an external server by performing an HTTP Get request. The server returns a list containing several numbers, which I need for further treatment. After replacement of infos I don´t need, the list looks like this:

```
  <int>123</int>
  <int>987</int>
  <int>7536</int>
  <int>879812</int>
  <int>5697231</int>
```

The problem is that the list **CAN** look like this. It is also possible that the server answer could look like:

```
<int>189977</int>
<int>7897</int>
<int>77</int>
```

or just like:

```
<int>6</int>
```

You see, I don´t know how many numbers I will get as a response or even how long the single numbers are.

Every number represents one result, which is important for the user who performes the HTTP request. More precisely, these numbers are part of a search link from the other site (the server to whom the request is sent to).

My purpose is that after the user makes that request, he should be redirected to a page, where the links with the correct numbers inside are shown, so that the user can click on the links to find his suitable result.

My suggestion is to firstly **eliminate the "`<int>`" and "`</int>`"** in the list, than secondly **save every number** to something like a Var or ReactiveVar and than use them to **render the links** on that page.

I was able to save the numbers into a Session Variable (I am using Meteor) and render them on a page, but that isn´t really what I want. Unfortunately, I have no clue how to perform the other things...

Does anybody know how to achieve that? I would be really thankful for anything that helps!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a DOM parser to retrieve the values if they're already in XML.

```
// Add a <root> element so the XML can be parsed properly
const xml = '<root><int>123</int>' +
  '<int>987</int>' +
  '<int>7536</int>' +
  '<int>879812</int>' +
  '<int>5697231</int></root>';

const parser = new DOMParser();
const xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xml,'text/xml');

const intElements = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('int');

let ints = [];

for (const intElement of intElements) {
  // Use parseInt() to convert the strings to numbers
  ints.push(parseInt(intElement.childNodes[0].nodeValue, 10));
}

// Use ints as you would like    
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(ints);
```

Comment: Pretty cool, that definitely helped me! It works as expected with your values. Now I get [123,987,7536,879812,5697231] with that server response. However, is it possible to insert the list as a variable instead? Because as I mentioned, the list could look differently and when I put my SessionVar between the <root> </root>, it doesn´t work anymore. In that case, I only get [ ] as a result. Or would it be even better, if I save every number itself to a var? Or loop through one variable? Because, I need to create a link with every number which comes in. Anyway, many thanks!

Comment: Ok, it was a typo, I can insert the variable... Now I just need to find out how to create the links out of the result and I think I will find out soon, so many thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! Sorry for the slight delay, but i would just keep the entire list of `ints` in a single variable. As for the creation of links, assuming you're using Blaze, create a template with `#each`, and then use that template. See [Blaze documentation](http://blazejs.org/guide/spacebars.html).